# Postman Pre-request Script for runner

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I know I can add a Pre-request Script for a collection or for a specific request.
I want to know if there is a way to do such a thing for a whole runner. I need it since I want to do `pm.collectionVariables.unset("myVar")` just once before my runner run, and not in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native pre-runner script for Postman collection/folder runs. There might be a few options here.

My solution would be to just have your first request be a `GET` to [Postman Echo](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/folder/19391207-0f2d68d4-e977-4c3f-86db-f191556ee528?ctx=documentation) that you can name runner initializer. The only goal of that request would be to do setup clean up. If you don't have network access to Postman echo, I would try to use something similar internally that just works as an automatic response.

I [created a sample folder](https://www.postman.com/southlondon/workspace/stackoverflow/folder/19391207-0f2d68d4-e977-4c3f-86db-f191556ee528?ctx=documentation) to illustrate the point.

[image]